# Adding Row via VBA based on condition

Tags: excel, vba

I use a VBA code to issue letters to defaulters. The data is maintained product-wise. If the Person1 has to pay for product1 it prints the SHEET2 (having data acquired from several other sheets) 
If the same person has to pay for product2 it prints a second letter. 
I am looking for a solution that if a person is repeated the code should add a row to an existing letter.

```
Sub Complaintexporter()

Dim X As Integer
Dim rng As Range


X = 3
Do Until IsEmpty(Sheet1.Cells(X, 29))

If Sheet1.Cells(X, 29) = "Legal Issued to Exporter" And Date - Sheet1.Cells(X, 36) > 21 Then
Sheet9.Cells(1, 1) = Sheet1.Cells(X, 4)
Set rng = Sheet1.Cells(X, 4)
'
'Sheet1.Activate
'    Cells.Find(What:=Sheet9.Cells(1, 1), After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
'        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
'        , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
       'Remarks
        Sheet1.Cells(X, 4).Offset(0, 25).Value = "Pending In FEA Court"
        'FEAD/FEOD
        Sheet1.Cells(X, 4).Offset(0, 24).Value = "FEAD"
        'Details Penalty
        Sheet1.Cells(X, 4).Offset(0, 26).Value = "Pending In FEA Court"
        'year
        Sheet1.Cells(X, 4).Offset(0, 28).Value = "2019"
        'Complaint against
        Sheet1.Cells(X, 4).Offset(0, 29).Value = "Exporter"
        'Complainant/ Officer
        Sheet1.Cells(X, 4).Offset(0, 36).Value = Sheet1.Cells(1, 4)
        'Complaint No
        Sheet1.Cells(X, 4).Offset(0, 27).Value = Sheet2.Cells(1, 2)
        'Date of complaint against exporter
        Sheet1.Cells(X, 4).Offset(0, 34).Value = Date

Sheet4.PrintOut
Sheet5.PrintOut
Sheet6.PrintOut

'Write E-Form in list
Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Cells(1, 1), 2) = Sheet9.Cells(1, 1)
'Write Date against E-Form
Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Cells(1, 1), 3) = Date
'Increasing Serial No.
Sheet2.Cells(1, 1) = Sheet2.Cells(1, 1) + 1
'Increasing Complaint No.
Sheet2.Cells(1, 2) = Sheet2.Cells(1, 2) + 1

End If
X = X + 1
Loop
MsgBox Sheet2.Cells(12, 9)
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: I am trying to add code with unable to do it. I am new to stack. Please guide.

Comment: Does anybody have a solution for this?